# Loop breaking after action

Tags: java, loops, do-while

The do while loop ends after I complete one of the  options I have set out.
For example it says: Process finished with exit code 0, after I bought and deployed some troops.

What am I missing?!
I want it to keep on going until the person wishes otherwise or the player wins.

```
do {
        refresh();
        System.out.println("" +
                "Lobby\n\n" +
                "==========\n" +
                "Balance: "+balance+"\n" +
                "Production Per Tick: "+production+"\n"+
                "\n----------\n" +
                "Options\n" +
                "----------\n" +
                "1. Show map\n" +
                "2. Build troops\n" +
                "3. Move troops\n" +
                "4. Upgrade Production\n" +
                "5. End turn\n");
        minimenu = input.nextInt();
        if  (minimenu==1) {
            refresh();
            displayMap(map);
            System.out.println("" +
                    "Map Legend:\n" +
                    "------------\n" +
                    "0 = not occupied\n" +
                    "1 = US Territory\n" +
                    "2 = Terrorist Territory\n");
        }
        else if (minimenu==2) {
            int troop;

            refresh();
            System.out.println("" +
                    "Choose the troops you want to build\n" +
                    "-----------------------------------\n" +
                    "1. Special Force - 100$\n" +
                    "2. Tank - 500$ \n" +
                    "3. F-32 - 1500$ \n" +
                    "--->");
            troop = input.nextInt();

                int amount,troopCount;
                System.out.print("Number of Special Forces you want: ");
                troopCount = input.nextInt();
                amount = troopCount*100;
                System.out.println("\nTotal: "+amount+"$\n" +
                        "Type 1 to conform: \n");
                    if (input.nextInt() ==1)
                        balance = balance-amount;
                int X,Y;
                do {
                System.out.print("" +
                        "where do you want to deploy the troops? (Must deploy on own land!)\n" +
                        "Enter Y coordinate: ");
                        Y =  input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("\nEnter X Coordinate");
                        X = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println(map[Y][X]+"This One"); //test code

                    if (varifyDeployment(map[Y][X])) {
                        if (troop==1) {
                            US_SpecialForce[Y][X] += troopCount;
                            System.out.println("Success!");
                        }
                        else if (troop ==2) {
                            US_Tank[Y][X] += troopCount;
                            System.out.println("Success!");
                        }
                        else if (troop == 3) {
                            US_Air[Y][X] += troopCount;
                            System.out.println("Success!");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("Incorrect location, Try Again");
                }while (!varifyDeployment(map[Y][X]));
                    displayMap(US_SpecialForce); //test code

        }
    }while (minimenu==5);
```

Thank you

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your code.

Comment: `do { ... } while(b)` does the loop once and then keeps doing it while `b` is `true`.  If `b` is `false`, it stops running the loop.  Were you perhaps unclear on how this worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your logic is incorrect.  You have as your menu option #5

```
"5. End turn\n"
```

But your do-while loop condition is

```
}while (minimenu==5);
```

This will continue the loop only if `minimenu` if 5.  I think you want not equal to 5, so the loop will continue if it's not `5`, and it will end if it is `5`.

```
}while (minimenu != 5);
```

Comment: Exactly what the problem was. Thank you!